# How to check if a file exists, without using .path

Tags: python, path

Is there any way that you can check if a file exists in the same folder as the program without using:

```
os.path.isfile or os.path.exists
```

Comment: Why would you not use `os.path`?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `os.path` without 'changing paths all the time', as you outlined in your comment.

```
import os

def is_file_in_app_path(filename):
    app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    file_path = os.path.join(app_path, filename)
    return os.path.exists(file_path)
```

*Fixed as per @tdelaney's comment.*

Comment: `os.path.join` is a platform independent version of `'/'.join(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def openFile(filename):
    try:
        fd = os.open(filename, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)
    except:
        print "Nothing here"
        return None
    fobj = os.fdopen(fd, "w")
    return fobj
```